# Significance of ".$" when appended to an AngularJS filter object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand a section of code pertaining to filtering in AngularJS that I found on the documentation website. (cf. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter)

In particular, the `.$` appended to the object `search`, which is used in the following lines:

```
24.    Any: <input ng-model="search.$"> <br>
25.    Name only <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
26.    Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>
       ...
30.    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

Using a JSFiddle to hack around, I tried removing the `.$` and then typing text in the input field to apply filtering. This worked fine. So, in general, why should I even bother appending `.$` if the search filter can work without it?

I am quite new to AngularJS (as well as JS I suppose) and have been enjoying learning it so far. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the filter page, you will notice this line:

> That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above.

So basically it is saying that when you put just `ng-model="search"`, you are using a string search, which by default searches all string items within the array/object. When you use `search.$`, you are specifying that you want to search each item within an object. As the sentence explains, these are equivalent.

While just `search` achieves the same result with less code, I believe `.$` better explains the intentions of the filter in the example.

Comment: Thanks for that simple explanation! Shame on me for missing that piece of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It works to search on **all** properties of the objects. In case of `search.name` you search only for objects where the `name` property matches, but `search.$` searches on all properties.

> A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above.

From http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter